# Fast Fourier transform (np.fft.fft), how to mask/ignore some indices in array

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have input array:

```
x=np.array( [ [5,3,4,2,1,4,0,0],
              [2,3,4,2,1,0,0,0],
              [8,3,4,0,0,0,0,0],
              [1,3,4,2,3,1,2,0] ] )
```

Instead of zero , there can be any value. I want to ignore those indices.

I want to do np.fft.fft( x, axis = -1 ) .
How can I apply mask so it calculates ignoring zero values or until some indices ? Should I use zeros or any other value or other solution ?

Comment: Ignoring zeros? Do you mean that you want to compute an FFT of different length for each row of the array? The only way to do that is to loop over the rows of the array and compute individual FFTs.

Comment: But if you plan to do that: are you sure that is what you want to do? What is your reason for this? What results do you think you will obtain? I'm asking because it doesn't make much sense...

Comment: I'm experimenting with transformer in pytorch. The input sequences are of a different length , so they are zero padded.  For instance i have input with dimension 100x 20 x 512 (batch x sequence x embedding dimension) .  I want to apply fft along dimension 1  ,  which is zero padded.  It is going to be long loop if I have to transform every sequence separately...

Comment: Like when we use softmax , we can assign some values = (-inf) so the function ignores those values. Is it possible to do something similar for fft ?

Comment: Zeros is what gets you closest to “ignore”. But they affect the length of the FFT, and so do have an influence. Still, I don’t understand what you’re hoping to accomplish, so it’s hard to recommend anything. Do you understand what the FFT does? Or are you just randomly transforming data in the hopes of seeing improved prediction performance?

Comment: I'm trying to understand FNet: Mixing Tokens with Fourier Transforms , https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.03824 . I don't see that they used any masking or padding. They first tranform along embedding dimension , then along sequence dimension to achieve mixing tokens.

Comment: Sequences are always of different lengths for nlp tasks, I see that zero padding gives different values with fft compared with when we use just original sequence without padding.